# Collapse animation when stop :hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm having a lot of troubles trying to do this. I finally found how to do an expansion animation for an aside menu im doing, when I hover one of its elements.

The problem is that i want to do an animation to close it as well. I tried making an animation as the open animation (with from -> to) and it doesn't work.

I tried making transitions with max height, using the different containers in the list (ul, div, li, whatever one by one), I tried searching different kinds of already made animations, but none worked, the menu just pop out and disappear without animation.

What I basically want is a smooth animation to move the other elements down (reached), and then up when the menu closes.

Actually it has 2 animations: to expand the max height, and to move it from right to left. but I can't reach to close it with animation.

I don't want to use Javascript, because is for school project but we haven't seen it yet.

https://jsfiddle.net/exrp4doa/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
  from {
    border-left: 300px
  }
  to {
    border-left: 0px
  }
}

@keyframes slider {
  from {
    margin-left: 300px
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes altura {
  from {
    max-height: 0px
  }
  to {
    max-height: 500px
  }
}

@keyframes altura {
  from {
    max-height: 0px
  }
  to {
    max-height: 500px
  }
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

aside > div:not(#marcador) {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#marcador div {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: static;
}

#marcador li:hover >div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-animation-name: slider;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: slider;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

#marcador li li {}

#marcador li:hover li {
  -webkit-animation-name: altura;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: altura;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

#marcador li:hover >a {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#marcador ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: static;
}

#marcador ul li>a {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#marcador ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#marcador ul ul a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#marcador ul ul ul a {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#marcador img {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

#marcador li:hover>a>img {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#marcador a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div id="marcador">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Inicio</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Juegos</a>
        <div>
          <ul>

            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Sega</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Arcade</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Nintendo</a>
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />SNES</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />NES</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Consolas</a>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />SNES Mini</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />NES Mini</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />SEGA GENESIS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Compras</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />DIY</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a onclick="alert('Página en construcción')"><img id="info" src="Recursos/info.png" alt="INFO" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transition instead of animation. My demo:

```css
 aside {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

aside > div:not(#marcador) {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#marcador li> div {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#marcador li:hover > div {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#marcador li> div >ul >li {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#marcador li:hover> div >ul >li {
  max-height: 40px;
}

#marcador li:hover{
  max-height: 500px !important;
}

#marcador li:hover > a {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#marcador ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: static;
}

#marcador ul li > a {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#marcador ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#marcador ul ul a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#marcador ul ul ul a {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#marcador img {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

#marcador li:hover > a > img {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#marcador a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div id="marcador">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Inicio</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Juegos</a>
        <div>
          <ul>

            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Sega</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Arcade</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Nintendo</a>
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />SNES</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />NES</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Consolas</a>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />SNES Mini</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />NES Mini</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />SEGA GENESIS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />Compras</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png" />DIY</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a onclick="alert('Página en construcción')"><img id="info" src="Recursos/info.png" alt="INFO" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```